# Facebook account restricted due to two-factor authentication but it is already switched on

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

After trying to log a client into my Meta App (using Facebook Login for Business), I found that their account is marked as restricted and it is failing to log in. There is a message saying "Turn on two-factor authentication to gain access to your business accounts and assets"

[image]

After clicking 'Secure Your Account' it takes me to a page saying that two-factor authentication is already set up:

[image]

I also tried accessing it from their 'personal' Facebook profile, but it says it is already turned on there too:

[image]

Are there more settings somewhere that can be used to fix this and remove the account restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the 2FA off and then on again solved it for me.